# What is the "Verifying XXX.app" dialog and how do I get passed it?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to open a new app that I downloaded on OS X Yosemite 10.10.  Specifically, it is Android Studio.app version 0.8.13.

When I open it, I see the following dialog "Verifying Android Studio.app...":

[image]

The progress bar has been at 100% for about 10 minutes and it hasn't gone away.  Granted, this app is rather large at about 25gb of SDK that needs to be included in the directory.

How do I get passed this dialog?

Answer (score 11):

One option to close stuck verification dialogs is to select CoreServicesUIAgent in the Activity Monitor's list of processes and kill it.

Or type in Terminal

```
 killall CoreServicesUIAgent
```

Comment: This did work for me (as in it got rid of the dialogs), but will that cause anything else to glitch? Also, the dialogs came up for an app that I had just *closed* which makes no sense, and further, what good is the X button next to that progress bar if it doesn't do a ****ing thing? ;)

Comment: I didn't run into other issues after killing the dialog. It looks more like a UI glitch. The system will pop up another dialog if needed.

Comment: The `killall` command doesn't do anyhting for me

Comment: Even with `sudo`. But the Activity Monitor worked!

Answer (score 3):

Just wait longer for the verification process to complete.

I had a similar situation with a 300 mb .app file.  I would get [Verifying "name_of_app.app"...], the percentage bar would be at 100% and it would hang for minutes.  I assumed there was a problem and came across your question while looking for an answer.  In the end I just left my MBP (mid-2010) alone for a few hours, came back and it was done verifying.  I recreated the conditions again and roughly timed it.  For a 300 mb .app file it took about 20 min to completely verify.

I was tempted to disable the verification using [the process described here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216188/apps-not-opening-verifying) but waiting it out worked in this case.

Happy waiting.

Answer (score 2):

The answer seemed to be to move the very large SDK out of the /Applications/Android Studio.app directory, then launch Android Studio, quit Android Studio, and move the sdk directory back into the /Applications/Android Studio.app directory.

After doing that, the Android Studio app launched fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Just move your IDE inside *"Applications"* folder.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).